# Nservicebus failing to start on localsystem

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus4

I recently upgraded to v4.6 of nservicebus and when I am trying to start locally using services.msc, it is throwing error "services on local system started and stopped". Can't make out what is missing.

I can use command line to start the nservicebus using like this:

```
NServiceBus.Host.Exe NServiceBus.Master NService.Integration
```

Comment: Look in the Windows `Event Viewer` to see if there is an exception visible?

Comment: I already looked in event viewer, there is no events or information regarding this.

Comment: Check the local log file for errors.  I think the default location is the application directory.

Comment: We experienced similar issue at one location and it was solved by enabling the setting "allow service to interact with desktop". I know this sounds crazy but worth trying.